# Device screen dimension has weird effect on scaled ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Update:
The multiple device screen dimensions is a red herring - the problem is just that the image does not scale up properly to fill the screen - see comments on Ivan's answer.

I have a layout file with one image:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Then I assign a drawable, which is small and must be scaled up:

```
setContentView(R.layout.image_story);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(s.image);
```

Here is how it is rendered on two AVDs with different screen dimensions. These should be the same (detailed question at the bottom). Sorry for the large images.

with scaleType=centerCrop:

[image]
[image]

with centerInside

[image]
[image]

AVDs:

[image]
[image]

Edit:

With layout_height="fill_parent" and scaleType="centerInside"

[image]
[image]

I have a 2.1 AVD with the default values, so the screen is smaller, and this works exactly as expected- the image is scaled up to fill the width, and the view height is wrapped to the scaled height.

On my Droid Bionic with a longer screen, and on any AVD with the same screen dimensions, this doesn't work- the image is scaled to fill the width, but the view is wrapped to the **original** pre-scale image height, so the top and bottom are cropped off.

I have no idea why the device screen aspect ratio would have an effect on this. I've tried countless combination of layout parameters and scale types trying to get this to work on the Bionic. Everything works exactly as expected on the smaller screen, and not on the larger. If I set the image height explicitly in `dp`, it works as expected, but I never know what the dimensions of the image (or screen) will be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Screenshots might be helpful as I'm not quite sure I am picturing the right thing.

Comment: Screenshots added- does that help? The smaller screen is giving the expected results in scaling up the image. The larger is using the unscaled size for sizing the ImageView.

Comment: Are you sure you want layout_height=wrap_content?

Comment: I want the height of the `ImageView` to be no larger than the scaled image, because the final version will have more views beneath the image, so I believe so, yes. I have updated the question with screenshots of height=fill_parent since that does not work properly either.

Comment: And what is the question? Write it in the end of your post please

Comment: I moved the question part to the bottom, if that helps.

Comment: try add to xml  - android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: With the scaleType as fitXY, the image is stretched to fill the screen, as expected, on both types of devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a very good question indeed.

Here's the reason it's behaving like that (from [ImageView.onMeasure(int, int) [line 661]](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/ImageView.java#661)):

```
// Try adjusting height to be proportional to width
if (!done && resizeHeight) {
    int newHeight = (int)((widthSize - pleft - pright)
            / desiredAspect) + ptop + pbottom;
    if (newHeight <= heightSize) { // line 661
        heightSize = newHeight;
    } // line 663
}
```

What it does is it adjusts the height of the view only if the new height that is based on aspect ratio of the drawable and the adjusted width (in our case, that's exact width of the parent view) is *smaller* than the adjusted height (which at this poin is just drawable's native height plus padding in our case. Let me know if you want me to brake down this point further.)

What I don't get is why is there the restriction that new height must be smaller. It makes sense only if our heightSize is either EXACTLY or AT_MOST and has been set to the upper bound. In other cases it's not necessary for it to be so.

So actually instead of the whole piece 661 through 663 there should have been another call to

```
heightSize = resolveAdjustedSize(newHeight, mMaxHeight, heightSpec);
```

to make sure we only use the height restriction when it should be restricted (ie. we got AT_MOST restriction in heightSpec and the height value in heightSpec is smaller than the new height. EXACTLY can't happen here unless we use variable width.)

Maybe, I missed something there. Guys, whoever is reading this, **please comment if you see any flaws** in that, especially if you're part of Android team at Google :)

**PS** As a workaround, I can suggest you implement a custom ImageView and override *onMeasure(int, int)* to set the bounds to your exact aspect ratio. Let me know if you need help on the actual code.

**UPD** I'm going to write out names to catch attention of smart android guys at Google (I'm hoping the guys have Google Alerts set up): Romain Guy, Roman Nurik, Reto Meier, please, take a look at this discussion.

Comment: In fact, only if `newHeight` is smaller then `heightSize` the following adjustment makes sense, otherwise (if it's greater) we would have adjusted the **width** by the code which is few lines before.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. There's a section above that adjusts width, but it only adjusts newWidth, which is not used in the piece that i posted, so it wouldn't compensate for newHeight being bigger than height size. Also, that section actually depends on the way width has been constrained by layout_width attribute. If layout_with="fill_parent", the width adjustment section will never get executed because resizeWidth will always be false. Nevertheless, we still need to adjust height, I don't see why only in cases where newHeight is smaller than heightSize. Am I missing something?

Comment: [This part of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/ImageView.java#647) does adjust `widthSize`. Note that if `done` is set to true, no height adjustment will be performed.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But that part is only executed if `resizeWidth` is `true`, and in our case it's not - because of the `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` resizeWidth is set to `false` on [line 608](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/ImageView.java#608).
So, `done` is not set to `true`, `resolveAdjustedSize()` sets `widthSize` to what's in `widthMeasureSpec` (width of the screen in our case). So, `newHeight` gets a value of screen width divided by image's aspect ratio, but isn't set because of the if clause on line 661

Comment: The only weak link here is that `fill_parent` causes `widthMeasureSpec`'s mode to be `EXACTLY`. I'm not 100 percent sure of it.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be so difficult! Thanks for the detailed answer, Ivan. I loaded the Android source so I can debug ImageView alongside my code, and what you say is correct. The comments indicate that `widthSize` and `heightSize` are initialized as the max possible w and h. If that were the case, then line 661 would make sense. But `heightSize` is just set to the native size of the image, and `resolveAdjustedSize()` considers it to be the 'desired', and it will scale down but not up. Also I think that setting `widthMeasureSpec` to `EXACTLY` is correct, as it's set to the width

Comment: of the parent view. Another interesting thing is that this is actually behaving exactly the same on the two device screens. It was only an illusion that it worked on the smaller screen, because the width of the screen is closer to the width of the image. On both, the ImageView height is limited to the height of the image.

Comment: I mean, limited to the height of the image before it is scaled. Which must be what `wrap_content` wants to do, when I want it to use the scaled height. Maybe I will just try to override onMeasure per your suggestion. I still feel as if I must be misunderstanding something, though.

Comment: Yeah, i get the feeling, too. I think I'll go through the code a couple more times to be sure. For overriding the method, you can even just copy over the whole class and just change the height adjustment (extending won't work, most members are private - which is another rather weird thing about Android sources. I once had to copypaste the whole ArrayAdapter just to slightly change the way it's text filter works). I think I'll try to attract the Google guys into this post, maybe we're all missing something here.

Comment: I subclassed ImageView like so: https://gist.github.com/1837629 and use with fitStart, which works perfectly for my particular case, although it isn't a great solution. I just saw your edit, I'll leave it open for a bit longer.

Comment: Well, maybe there is no better solution, I guess I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: I tried writing to Romain, no luck yet) I'll maybe try nagging the guys for some time more.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to scale the image maintaining its aspect ratio. `scaleType="fitCenter"` should give you the desired behavior:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

If it doesn't help, try adding this to the manifest file:

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: `fitCenter` does not scale the image up, just displays it at the top of the screen at original size (like the big "fill_parent" and scaleType="centerInside", but at the top of the screen). Adding `supports-screens` to the manifest doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `ImageView` into some layout (`LinearLayout`, e.g.) and then calling `setContentView(..)` for this layout? I'd experiment with different combinations of layouts and layout params.

Comment: Yeah, haven't found the right combo. Otherwise I'm using `setContentView` on the layout file with only the `ImageView` for testing and that seems to be the same as a `LinearLayout` with a single child element.